# ConstraintLayout Barrier not working properly when parent dimensions are set to wrap_content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, constraintlayout-barrier

Here's a reproduction of my issue:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/textView2"
        android:text="Text"/>
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="muchlongertextmuchlongertextmuchlongertextmuchlongertextmuchlongertextmuchlongertextmuchlongertextmuchlongertextmuchlongertextmuchlongertextmuchlongertext"/>
    
    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="textView, textView2"/>
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/barrier"
        android:text="muchlongertextmuchlongertextmuchlongertextmuchlongertextmuchlongertextmuchlongertextmuchlongertextmuchlongertextmuchlongertextmuchlongertextmuchlongertext"/>
    
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

When you set the parent height to `match_parent`, the Barrier works as intended. But, as soon as you set it to `wrap_content`, it doesn't do the layout properly.

Here's how it looks with `wrap_content`, and at the right with `match_parent`:

[image]
[image]

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated. I didn't find anyone advocating against using Barriers this way, but didn't find anyone who got that kind of layout working.

Is that a mistake on my part or is that a bug in Barrier?

Comment: Check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71216910/constraint-layout-barrier-not-working-as-expected

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is not clear what you mean by "parent". If I set the height of the `ConstraintLayout` (the only parent I can see) to `match_parent`, nothing changes. The result is as your first picture.

What you have to do, to make the barrier hold back the bottom `textView3` is to complete the vertical chain between `textView`, `textView2` and `barrier`. The code will then look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/barrier"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="muchlongertextmuchlongertextmuchlongertextmuchlongertextmuchlongertextmuchlongertextmuchlongertextmuchlongertextmuchlongertextmuchlongertextmuchlongertext"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/barrier"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="textView, textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="muchlongertextmuchlongertextmuchlongertextmuchlongertextmuchlongertextmuchlongertextmuchlongertextmuchlongertextmuchlongertextmuchlongertextmuchlongertext"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/barrier" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: But how do I keep the smaller top textview to stay aligned to the top of constraintlayout?

Comment: Nevermind. I just set vertical_bias to 0. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. How did you set the vertical bias to 0?

Comment: why do have to set  `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/barrier"`, it's a task for barrier to detect max height for specified views

Comment: also in this case you have to set vertical bias to 0 for text views, if you don't them centered ....