# Constraint layout barrier not working as expected

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, constraintlayout-barrier

I have 2 views and I need a barrier below but the barrier does not work as expected.
Here is my layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a text view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/t1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/t1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView15"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is a demo text to check wrap content"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="textView15,t1"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Constraint layout preview]

The black dotted line is the barrier.

This might be a bug or I am doing it wrong, The result is same in preview and actual device

Comment: You are doing it right. This seems to be an issue with _ConstraintLayout_ 2.1.3. Version 2.0.4 works if you can drop back. Other versions may be OK, too, but I haven't checked.

Comment: I checked with other versions and all the versions have same problem from 2.0.1 onwards.. I had to roll back to version 2.0.0

Comment: I have a solution that I will post as an answer since it may help others.

Comment: @AnkitVerma, thanks for 2.0.0 version. Now it moves <Barrier> when <TextInputLayout> shows `error`.

Comment: downgrade to v 2.0.4 worked

Comment: app:layout_constrainedHeight="true" add this in your text views it will work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you specify

```
app:layout_optimizationLevel="none"
```

in the XML for the *ConstraintLayout*, you will find that the barrier will be placed correctly. I am not sure what setting the optimization level achieves, but it has been an issue recently with barriers. (*ConstraintLayout* version 2.1.3).

Here is how the layout looks before suppressing optimization. The barrier rises up into the right *TextView* as noted.

[image]

We suppress optimization by stating in the XML with no other changes:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_optimizationLevel="none"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
```

Now the layout looks like this:

[image]

The barrier has dropped below the right *TextView* where it belongs.

This is with *ConstraintLayout* version 2.1.3.

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
```

*(It seems that setting optimization level to anything but `standard` solves this problem.)*

Comment: This answer doesn't work as well.

Comment: @AnkitVerma Take a look at the updated answer that now has an example. I would be curious if you get a different result.

Comment: This time  your code worked . All it needed was a rebuild.

Comment: Doesn't work for TextInputLayout error and Barrier.

Comment: Instead of suppressing the layout optimization.  just add constrained height as true in the elements.

app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:text="This is a text view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/t1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/t1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView15"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is a demo text to check wrap content"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="textView15,t1"/>
    <Space
       android:id="@+id/space"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:visibility="visible"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/barrier" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You simply added <Space>, but it doesn't change a behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

As was written before, `ConstraintLayout` versions 2.1.3 and 2.1.4 work incorrectly, you can downgrade it to 2.0.0. If not, you can use two ways. In both cases remove `<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier>`.

1. Insert `LinearLayout` to occupy needed views. For instance, if you have 2 `TextInputLayout`s in horizontal position, you can write so:

   ```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/upper_view">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            ...


        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            ...
    </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. If you have a complex layout with different views, write so.

   ```
   <Space
        android:id="@+id/space"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/input_layout_2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/upper_view" />
   ```

   Then you should change `Space` height in code. Probably you can apply this code to all `TextInputLayout`s.

   ```
    // View size change listener
    private fun View.onSizeChange(callback: () -> Unit) {
        addOnLayoutChangeListener(object : OnLayoutChangeListener {
            override fun onLayoutChange(
                view: View?,
                left: Int,
                top: Int,
                right: Int,
                bottom: Int,
                oldLeft: Int,
                oldTop: Int,
                oldRight: Int,
                oldBottom: Int,
            ) {
                view?.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this)
                if (right - left != oldRight - oldLeft || bottom - top != oldBottom - oldTop) {
                    callback()
                }
            }
        })
    }

    binding.inputLayout2.onSizeChange {
        // First remove bottom constraint
        val layoutParams = binding.space.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
        layoutParams.bottomToBottom = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.UNSET
        // Now set height of a <Space> (maximum of two TextInputLayouts)
        val h1 = binding.inputLayout1.height
        val h2 = binding.inputLayout2.height
        binding.inputLayout2.postDelayed({
            binding.space.updateLayoutParams { height = max(h1, h2) }
        }, 1)
    }
   ```

Then bind bottom views to `LinearLayout` or `Space` instead of `Barrier`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
```

To views referenced by barrier solved my problem.