# Android studio: Barrier does not take into account line breaks

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to put barrier under buttons, switches and list. The barrier is set right, but only if screen is wide enough to fit switch text in one line (attached images).

One line:

[image: One line]

Two lines:

[image: Two lines]

Three lines:

[image: Three lines]

I have tried changing barriers parameters from `wrap_content` to two others. Also tried `0dp`, per example found on internet.

As you can see in attached images, the barrier does not move with bigger switch text.

Here's the code. It's a cut version, just to show the problem. It is put into scroll view because smaller screens do not fit everything.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id = "@+id/big_scroll"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="450dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".17" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".40"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="FIRST OPTION"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/list"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/list" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".40"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="SECOND OPTION. BALALALALA. YADADADADA."
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/list"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/switch1"/>



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="OKAY"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/list"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/switch2"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".40" />


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/labelBarrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="button3" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Although list (on the left) has working barrier.

Comment: Is it only showing this during preview or have you tried running your code and check the actual layout on the device? Sometimes barriers are incorrect on the preview screen than the actual result is what I’ve personally observed.

Comment: Hi, yes same with actual device. I added button after barrier - it retains in same position as with single line switch text. On smaller device the new button is even higher than "OKAY" button, as there are even more line breaks.

Comment: Try adding all ids to barrier reference ids that you need barrier to be below of.

Comment: Just tried - no. List barrier is okay, but as soon as I add many letters to switch, it still goes through the barrier. Its like barrier does not know the size of the text? It assumes switch is single line?

Comment: I figured it out! The percentage width is what messes it up. I replaced it with "match_parent" and it works. But I need the width in percentage...

Comment: You layout looks OK. Maybe you are having [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71226573/6287910).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use guidelines instead of percentage. That way line breaks dont have influence on the rest of design.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2" />
```

Such guideline will be at percentage of 20%. Then I use few more until I can wrap my content the way I want.